# multiprocessing web pages

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Can anyone help me this little code to work... I want to open several web pages via python in parallel, but its not working.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
def process_url(url):
    # Do what you want
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(workers=4) 
list_of_urls=['www.page1.com','www.page1.com','www.page1.com','www.page1.com/']
print(pool.map(process_url, list_of_urls))
```

I got an error:

```
TypeError: Pool() got an unexpected keyword argument 'workers'
```

when i change it without workers, i got indefinite loop.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
def process_url(url):
    # Do what you want
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4) # how much parallelism?
list_of_urls=['www.page1.com','www.page1.com','www.page1.com','www.page1.com/']
print(pool.map(process_url, list_of_urls))
```

I took this code from another question asked.

Comment: How do you know that this is an infinite loop ?

Comment: Becouse it lasts forever..

Comment: Are you sure it is not just waiting indefinitely (without looping) for the connection or something ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. It just waiting indefinitely (without looping). Thank you for correction

Comment: hivert do you have some suggestion about a code? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

The following code where I fixed various import problems works for me:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
import urllib
import urllib.request

def process_url(url):
    print("doing")
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    print("done")
    return res

pool = Pool(4) # how much parallelism?
list_of_urls=['http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com/']
print(pool.map(process_url, list_of_urls))
```

Please post a complete example or fix your import.

Comment: It's not even printing "doing", for some reason it's not calling or entering the function. Libraries are good, becouse i dont have problem rading page by page without multiprocessing..

Comment: Version of Python ? Os ? Environment ?

Comment: It's Python 3.3.2 on Windows 7

Comment: Then I can't help ! Sorry. By the way did you read http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows ?

Comment: `def process_url(url):
    print("doing")
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    print("done")
    return res

list_of_urls=['http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com','http://www.google.com/']
b=[]
for url in list_of_urls:
    b.append(process_url(url))`
If i try this everything is OK..

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found solution, i need tu put this "if **name** == '**main**':" if i want it to be printed. For some reason Python IDLE not works for multiprocessing. Hivert thank you very much. I have red this on  docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
def process_url(url):
    # Do what you want
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(workers=4) 
    list_of_urls=['www.page1.com','www.page1.com','www.page1.com','www.page1.com/']
    print(pool.map(process_url, list_of_urls))
```